# Wifi problems with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I should probably say straight off that I am brand new to Ubuntu. I installed 13.10 alongside Windows 7 a couple of days ago and I've managed to clear up all the little problems, apart from with the wifi.

My internet is fine using an ethernet cable. I can connect to the wifi, and it tells me that the signal is good, but for the vast majority of the time I can't load anything, and system monitor tells me that I am sending and receiving nothing.

The problem is somewhere in Ubuntu. It works fine on Windows 7, my Android phone and all of my flatmates laptops. I know I'm not the only one with this problem, but the fixes I've seen either don't work or I don't understand them enough to carry them out. Help?

EDIT: `sudo killall NetworkManager` works sometimes, thanks for the tip, but I have to keep doing it every few minutes, which is really not practical.

EDIT: from `lspci` command as requested

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information on the hardware you are using? It would be helpful if you could post the output of the `lspci` command (open a terminal window and type `lspci`).

Comment: my wi-fi is going dead after suspend on 13.10. I have to perform "sudo killall NetworkManager" to work again

Comment: Would anything bad happen if I tried that?

Comment: Tosho I've that problem also. Thanks for the tip though. I always have to reiniciate it...after suspension....

Comment: Mine isn't going dead after suspend, it's just amazingly patchy. Is there no fix for this?